# Converting Charts and ScoreCards rendered by Performancepoint Server to images

Tags: c#, sharepoint-2007, performancepoint

Is there a way to convert pps charts and scorecards to image ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

found a work around 
made mdx query to cube , sorted the data and manually generated charts using msChart .
Dirty , time taking , but effective .

Answer (score 0):

You can create a PPS pivot chart in dashboard designer and check the box at the bottom to `Display as Image`.

I don't believe you can do the same with a scorecard.